# Magento 2: How to pass variable to template from another template?

Tags: magento2, blocks, template

I want to pass product as variable from **list.phtml** to another template file which i will called there using below code

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("Test_Module::Test/view/config.phtml")->toHtml();
```

I've found that for Magento 1 we can use below code.

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('module/template_name')
->setData('key', 'some value')
->setTemplate('module/newblock.phtml')->toHtml();
```

And we can access of this variable to that template using below syntax

```
echo $this->key;
```

I've tried same for Magento 2 using below code but no luck.

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setData('key', 'd')->setTemplate("Test_Module::Test/view/config.phtml")->toHtml();
```

I can see blank page when tried to get value using below code.

```
echo $this->key;
```

Anyone have tried similar to it?

Comment: Maybe will helpfull this answer for same question
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/352441/9951

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried this it's worked for me

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setKey('dfd')->setTemplate("Test_Module::Test/view/config.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
```

to get value

```
$block->getKey();
```

also change your method will work too

```
 echo $this->key;
```

to

```
echo $this->getKey();
```

Comment: Its work but i've problem if block is different rather than `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`. I have another methods on block which  i called there.

Comment: @Kul it doesnot matter just use `$this->getKey()` in your block it will work too.

Comment: Great Its work. I've another issue with block that's why it doesn't work first time.