# Magento2 - How to hide price filter only in specific categories?

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, filtered-nav

I want to hide price filter on some of my category pages.
[image]

Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this?

Thanks In Advance..!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using following code. I have created a plugin in custom module.

**app/code/Anshu/HideFilters/registration.php**

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(
    ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Anshu_HideFilters',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/Anshu/HideFilters/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Anshu_HideFilters">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/Anshu/HideFilters/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList">
        <plugin name="hideFilters_plugin" type="Anshu\HideFilters\Plugin\FilterPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/Anshu/HideFilters/Plugin/FilterPlugin.php**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Anshu\HideFilters\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;

class FilterPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var Http
     */
    private $request;

    public function __construct(
        Http $request
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function afterGetFilters(FilterList $subject, $result)
    {
        $catId = $this->request->getParam('id');
        if($catId != '21') {
            return $result;
        }
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($result as $r){
            if($r->getName() == 'Price'){
                unset($result[$count]);
                return $result;
            }
            $count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Here I am hiding Price filter for category with ID 21.

Modify it according to your requirement.

Comment: It worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the following file

> app/design/frontend/vendor/your_theme/Magento_LayeredNavigation/templates/layer/view.phtml

Add your logic around the foreach function of **$block->getFilters()** as shown below

```
<?php
    // create an array of the category ids in which you don't want the price filter
    $restricted_categories = [3, 4, 10, 14];
    $currentCategoryId = $block->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
?>
.....
.....
.....
<?php foreach ($block->getFilters() as $filter): ?>
    <?php
        if (in_array($currentCategoryId, $restricted_categories) && $filter->getRequestVar() == 'price') {
            continue;
        }
    ?>
    .....
    .....
    .....
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Note:** It seems that you are using any third party extension for Layered Navigation. If so, you have to use this code in the file of your extension.

Answer (score 0):

**Can hide Filters with minimum modify in PHTML Theme template.**

1. Add XML instruction to Category Edit Page - field **Layout Update XML**

> ```
> <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
>     <referenceBlock name="catalog.leftnav">
>         <action method="assign">
>             <argument name="key" xsi:type="string">filterhide</argument>
>             <argument name="value" xsi:type="array">
>                 <item name="filter1" xsi:type="string">filter1</item>
>                 <item name="filter2" xsi:type="string">filter2</item>
>                 <item name="filter3" xsi:type="string">filter3</item>
>                 <item name="filter4" xsi:type="string">filter4</item>
>                 <item name="filter5" xsi:type="string">filter5</item>
>             </argument>
>          </action>
>     </referenceBlock>
> </referenceContainer>
> ```

2. Update PHTML theme template
   Edit Theme file **Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/view.phtml**
   Add following code:

> ```
> <?php
> $filterhideVar = false;
> if (isset($filterhide) && is_array($filterhide)) {
>     $sfilterhideVar = $filterhide;
> }
> ?>
> ```

And for hide filter add:
After construction 
`<?php foreach ($block->getFilters() as $filter) : ?>`

Add following piece of PHP code:

```
 if (isset($filterhideVar) &&
 isset($filterhideVar[$filter>getAttributeModel()->getAttributeCode()]))
 {continue;}
```

Same method can pass custom vars from Adminpanel to Phtml.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can try using this code

app/design/frontend/YOURPACKAGE/YOURTEMPLATE>template>catalog/layer/view.phtml

```
  <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()):?>
  <?php $show=1;?>
    <!-- curern filter price and currentc Cat match -->
  <?php if($_filter->getFilter()->getRequestVar()!=='price'){?>
    <?php if(Mage::registry('current_category') &&(Mage::registry('current_category')->getId()==$catId)):
    $show=0;
        endif;
     ?>
  <?php } ?>
  <!-- check show 
  <?php if($show==1){?>
  <?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php endif;?>
```

Or you can also refer to this [link](https://www.manadev.com/documentation/magento-2-guides/seo-layered-navigation-plus/how-to/how-to-hide-a-filter-in-specific-category)

Comment: OP has tagged this with Magento 2 and this appears to be an answer for Magento 2